# Is it possible to pass function variable to model field queryset in Django?

Tags: django, function, filter, model, field

I have in my model a ForeignKey which is gonna get the organization id filtered by admin user role.

user_group_validation function goes like this...

```
def user_group_validation(request):
var = {}
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    groups = request.user.groups.all()

    var['group'] = DefaultLandingPage.objects.get(pk=groups).role.name
    var['tpl'] = DefaultLandingPage.objects.get(pk=groups).url
    return var
else:
    return 'sorry, not yet! =('
```

then we go trough the role_choice_organization function to get the organization for the provided role...

```
def role_choice_organization(self):
var = {}
var = user_group_validation(self.request)
userInc = Users.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id).organization_id.pk
self.request.session['userInc'] = userInc

if var['group'] == 'superuser':
    organization = Organizations.objects.all()
if var['group'] == 'admin' or var['group'] == 'user':
    organization = Organizations.objects.filter(id=self.request.session['userInc'])
```

return organization

and finally, I tried to get this organization returned value into my ForeignKey queryset, just like this ...

```
 organization_id = models.ForeignKey(organization, editable=True)
```

now the error I get with this code is that "organization is not defined" when I try to load it into the queryset of organization_id ForeignKey

Comment: You haven't explained what are `Users` model and `user_group_validation` function. `User` model is provided by Django. I have no idea what `Users` model is in your code. Why do you thing something is wrong with the code? Are you getting any error? Is yes, add error stacktrace to the question.

Comment: alright, below I´ll define them all

Comment: By the way, Users is my app model where I defined the organization_id field as ForeignKey